# Is VIP's Fairway Trolley (80cm) allowed for check-in for US trip in Etihad?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, international-travel, etihad

I'll be traveling to US next month via Etihad Airways. Etihad's baggage allowance policy states that "all check-in baggage must adhere to max dimensions 158 cm".
I bought this VIP bag from Amazon (https://www.amazon.in/dp/B07T2DQNGF/ref=cm_sw_r_wa_awdb_t1_RAsEDbHV6RJCX). Adding all the dimensions stated on the website, it comes down to 166 cm. I'm a bit worried on whether it'll be allowed without any additional baggage fees. Are the measurements mentioned on the website exact or slightly bigger than the actual? Can someone please advise me on this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a possibility you will have to pay, as I am reading on TripAdvisor they are very strict on bags:

> Etihad is extremely strict at check in on carry on baggage size, it's weight, and also the weight of checked baggage, so much so that at Abu Dhabi there are scales and areas for passengers to re-distribute contents across bags to balance weight variations.

Also, from [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/118618/do-etihad-airways-take-dimensions-of-the-check-in-baggage-seriously):

> Airlines do weigh checked baggage and that is the most important measurement, actual dimensions are almost never measured for 'normal' luggage. Even when they do, small differences are hardly ever a problem, especially if the overall dimensions are good.
>   There is, however, no guaranty a specific agent may measure and give you a harder time.
>   At this time there is no tradition of measuring luggage out of sight of the passenger and coming back to them with complains.
>
> If the rules change in the future, you might be stuck with a piece of luggage that can not be used on flights.

Comment: The question is about checked luggage.  I've certainly been on flights where my checked luggage was not measured and my carry on bags were.  The quoted material even says that Etihad is strict about the weight of checked bags but only mentions size in connection with carry-on bags.  That suggests that this bag is likely to be accepted if it is within the weight restriction.

Comment: @phoog airlines often have tape measures and are fined if they don't measure checked luggage

Comment: I have never had my checked luggage measured in 20 years of frequent transatlantic traveling.  I'll measure my bags tonight to see what their combined dimension is, but I suspect that at least one of them is larger than 158 cm.  As to the fine, who would fine the airline?  The baggage handlers' union?

Comment: @phoog edited, see post

Comment: I've upvoted this answer because there certainly *is* a possibility that the airline will charge.  None of my experience has been with Etihad, so I'd expect the chances are low but I can't say more than that.  If syfro is willing to risk it, as I might be, I would use the bag and find out for myself.  I also wonder whether the website measurement includes the protruding wheels, and whether the airline would include them when measuring the bag.